# React unit testing, enzyme/mocha testing (or mocking?) html image api

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have created a component for my project to help with some image loading. The component is working great for me however when trying to unit test I am running into some difficulties with the html Image api:

To start, my component is using the `new Image();` syntax to load in some images, here is the component

```
import React from 'react';

require('./progressive-image.scss');

export default class ProgressiveImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const small = this.refs['small-img'];
    const large = this.refs['large-img'];

    const img = new Image();

    img.src = this.props.smallImg;
    img.onload = function() {
      small.classList.add('loaded');
    };

    const imgLarge = new Image();

    imgLarge.src = this.props.largeImg;
    imgLarge.onload = function() {
      imgLarge.classList.add('loaded');
    };

    large.appendChild(imgLarge);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const small = this.refs['small-img'];
    const large = this.refs['large-img'];
    const sameImg = large.childNodes[2].src === this.props.largeImg;

    // if loading same img, do nothing
    if (!sameImg) {
      // remove loaded
      small.classList.remove('loaded');

      const img = new Image();

      img.src = this.props.smallImg;
      img.onload = function() {
        small.classList.add('loaded');
      };

      // remove old img
      large.childNodes[2].remove();

      const imgLarge = new Image();

      imgLarge.src = this.props.largeImg;
      imgLarge.onload = function() {
        imgLarge.classList.add('loaded');
      };

      large.appendChild(imgLarge);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const imgStyle = { 'paddingBottom': this.props.heightRatio };

    return (
        <div className="progressive-placeholder" ref="large-img">
          <img className="img-small" ref="small-img" />
          <div style={imgStyle} ></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ProgressiveImage.displayName = 'ProgressiveImage';

ProgressiveImage.propTypes = {
  bgColor: React.PropTypes.string,
  heightRatio: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  largeImg: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  smallImg: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Using enzymes `mount` to fully render, i am doing something like this to unit test the componentDidMount (and hopefully the componentdidupdate in the future).

```
    it('should load images on mount', () => {
    const instance = mount(
          <FollainProgressiveImage
            bgColor={bgColor}
            heightRatio={heightRatio}
            largeImg={largeImg}
            smallImg={smallImg}
            />
      );
  });
```

However the test runner is yelling at me that `Image is not defined`. So i tried something like

```
    it('should load images on mount', () => {
    global.Image = spy();
    const instance = mount(
          <FollainProgressiveImage
            bgColor={bgColor}
            heightRatio={heightRatio}
            largeImg={largeImg}
            smallImg={smallImg}
            />
      );
  });
```

That spy is a `sinon.spy`, however this gives me the error of `First argument to Node.prototype.appendChild must be a Node` , but i can see in the coverage report that the componentDidMount is being hit.

I am not sure how to best approach testing this, should I fully mock the object, or is there some better way to do this?

Just for reference - my test env is set up like :

```
global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = {userAgent: 'node.js'};
```

Maybe this needs to change?

Really stuck here, looking for any input in how to test this code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Image()` constructor is part of the browser and therefore not in Node.js. When you call `new Image()` in the browser it is equivalent to call `new window.Image()`. With `jsdom` you have set `global.window` to emulate the browser's `window`. That means you now have access to `window.Image`. If you want to make it available without the `window` prefix you can make it global, there is no need to make a spy or a mock manually. Simply add this to your test setup:

```
global.Image = window.Image;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this solved the problem and you helped me understand why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

Following the installation and Mocha instructions for [global-jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-jsdom) fixed this issue for me.